# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException(0x80004005) you have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I have this error when I try to create a connection with SQL and Visual Studio 2019.

```
namespace Visual_SQL
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
        }

        private void BtnConnection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string servidor = TXTServer.Text;
            string puerto = TXTPort.Text;
            string usuario = TXTUser.Text;
            string contraseña = TXTPassword.Text;
            string dato = "";

            string cadenaConexion = "server=" + servidor + "; port=" + puerto + "; user id=" + usuario + "; password=" + contraseña + "; database=mysql;";

            MySqlConnection conexionBD = new MySqlConnection(cadenaConexion); 

            try    
            {                 
                conexionBD.Open();

                MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader reader = null;

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Mostrar database", conexionBD);
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    dato += reader.GetString(0) + "\n";    
                }
            }
            catch(MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            MessageBox.Show(dato);
        }
    }
}
```

If someone could help me

[image]

Comment: What do you want MySQL to do with `"Mostrar database"` passed as a SQL command?  Suggested study material: **[Online SQL Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/index.htm)** Also, c# and C and c++ for that matter are not interchangable.  Mind your tags

Comment: So, what does `MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Mostrar database", conexionBD);` do?

Comment: As usual,  MySqlCommand's first parameter should be the the test of mysql code or stored procedure name. According your code, what do you want to get about the code?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SHOW DATABASES;", conexionBD);
```

To get all the databbases stored in your server;